# How can we use TaxJar with CraftCommerce?

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce, tax

Is there anything akin to a presave event or postsave event where we can make a call to TaxJar API to get calculate and report sales tax? I find the integrated tax system impractical at the moment. I would like to create a plugin that can access the existing tax api platforms, but need to know the best insertion points for this.

Answer (score 3):

The [onBeforeSaveOrder](https://craftcommerce.com/docs/events-reference#commerce_orders.onbeforesaveorder) event runs before all of the adjustments are calculated (including taxes), so it seems like that's what you're looking for.